# The Historicity of David, Pilate, and the Philistines

Tags: apologetics, david, textual-criticism, pilate, biblical-scholarship

I've looked at the discoveries of things like the Tel Dan Inscription or the Pilate Stone which testify to the existence of David and Pilate. I read that before such archeological discoveries, the existence of people like King David and Pontius Pilate was disputed. Now, it seems that most scholars accept the existence of David, and all accept Pilate existing from what I've seen.

Apparently, starting from somewhere around the 17th century, scholars were arguing against Biblical figures existing. They also argued against the Philistines' existence. Every apologist I encounter who brings up these discoveries starts off by saying "Skeptics used to say 'x', but because of these discoveries, we have evidence that 'y' is true, so they agree with us now."

But I cannot find many examples of skeptic scholars in the past who have denied the Philistines, David, Pilate, or many other people whose existence is disputed. Maybe I haven't done enough research. But these attacks on skeptics are found on basically all apologist websites defending the validity of the Bible. Here's one example of such a website from a good defender of the Word:

https://coldcasechristianity.com/writings/a-brief-sample-of-old-testament-archaeological-corroboration/

Could someone point me toward some evidence that the scholars doubted the existence of David, Pilate, and the Philistines back in the day? Thanks.

Comment: I feel like this isn't a good fit for this site. This site is about Christianity, not evidence of scholars who doubted biblical history.

Comment: Having failed to find any reliable source that documents scholars who deny the historicty of David and the Philistines, I can only point you to this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philistines

Comment: Bruno Bauer of the 19th century Tubingen school is one of the more famous skeptical scholars who denied that Pilate (and a whole bunch of other people) was a real person. Bauer's theories have not aged well.

Comment: Please provide evidence to support this claim you have made: "I read that before such archeological discoveries, the existence of people like King David and Pontius Pilate was disputed." Where did you read this? Which people disputed their existence?

Comment: @HoldToTheRod - There is no reference to Bruno Bauer disputing Old Testament places, characters and events.  Seems like his focus was on Christ Jesus, Paul and other N.T. writings.

Comment: @Lesley - This is the point of my question, I see no skeptics who disputed their existence. Here are a few Christian websites that claim that these people were disputed, I gave one earlier as well. I ask because many Christian YouTubers, websites, and people I know say these things. https://www.patternsofevidence.com/2018/12/22/pontius-pilates-ancient-ring/, https://free.messianicbible.com/feature/found-governor-city-seal-verifies-bible/, https://doesgodexist.today/philistine-people-dna/